# Could not parse W3C capabilities

Tags: java, macos, selenium, appium

On MacOS Big Sur (11.3.1), I'm new to [appium-mac2-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-mac2-driver), the code I have try to connect to appium server and receive an error. Even though I mention the `automationName` on the server and on the client.

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
(...)
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: (...)
[Appium] Could not parse W3C capabilities: 'automationName' can't be blank
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1628283706787 (22:01:46 GMT+0100 (Western European Summer Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: InvalidArgumentError: 'automationName' can't be blank
[debug] [W3C]     at processCapabilities (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/capabilities.js:217:13)
(...)
```

The appium server was initiated by `appium server -ka 800 --plugins=images -pa /wd/hub --nodeconfig appium-mac2.json`. The version of appium installed is `2.0.0-beta.12`.

The node configuration have the following capabilities:

```
{
  "capabilities":
    [
      {
        "automationName": "Mac2",
        "platform": "Mac",
        "platformVersion": "10.15",
        "deviceName": "Mac",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "appium:bundleId": "com.my.app"
      }
    ]
}
```

Then the client in java is being connected with the following code block:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("automationName", "Mac2");
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Mac");
caps.setCapability("bundleId", "com.my.app");
caps.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 30000);
RemoteWebDriver macDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```

This fails while trying to initiate a new session. The code fails at the `new RemoteWebDriver` line. I've been searching these error is common with other capabilities but not for `automationName`. Is there anything I doing wrong on the server or even on the client code?